# 751H running ubuntu12.04 Dont Starve boots to a black screen Audio only?

Tags: 12.04, acer, steam, aspire, gma500

I have an acer aspire one 751h with 2GB of ram and GMA500 graphics.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit.

I have steam loaded on the computer and it runs fine (slow in full screen) but fine. 
I installed Don't Starve onto the computer and it starts with a black screen with audio only.

I tried about 5 different options in the start up file inside steam (i.e. right click the game--preferences) I tried setting the height to 600 and the width to 800 I tried -gl, -safe and a few others none worked and most started crashing once the sound kicked in.

I tried updating the graphics drivers and no improvement. It still starts to a black screen till you hear the audio then it will crash. can anyone point me in the right direction to get this game to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your video is not supported by the game. Try running the game with a supported video card.

Graphics: Radeon HD5450 or better; dedicated 256 MB or higher (GMA Cards not supported - See below)

Source:http://www.dontstarvegame.com/specs

Comment: Thank you, ya Steam just says Graphics: Radeon HD5450 or better; dedicated 256 MB or higher. this game does not seem that graphic intensive, is a possible workaround available or a way to run the game in anyway? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you're unsure of this restriction, please feel free to ask in the official Don't Starve Forums: http://forums.kleientertainment.com/forum/5-dont-starve/  source:http://www.dontstarvegame.com/specs

Comment: If you find an answer here helpful, please upvote/accept it so that others can find it and benefit. Thank you!

Comment: Would the Broadcom BCM70012 miniPCI card help this run

Comment: I don't see how that would be helpful.